# Dynamic search ingine PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

How can I do a multiple search with many skills arguments ??????

```
 public function searchBySkills($pSkills){   
    $requete = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidat WHERE skillsCandidat LIKE :skillsCandidat ");
    $requete->bindValue(':skillsCandidat', '%'.$pSkills.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $requete->execute();
    $tab = $requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $this->listCandidat = array();
    foreach ($tab as $row) {

        $candidat = new Candidat();
        $candidat->fromPost($row);
        //var_dump($row);
        array_push($this->listCandidat, $candidat);
    }
}
```

The parameter $pSkills is an array

```
array (size=2)
 0 => string 'developper' (length=10)
 1 => string 'designer' (length=8)
```

I used to do like this :

```
$skills   = isset($_POST['skillsCandidat']) ? $_POST['skillsCandidat'] : '';
foreach($skills as $skill){
     $CandidatList->searchBySkills($skill);
}
```

Is there any other way ?? 
Thanks in advance for help !

Comment: you build a query string that has `where skills LIKE :arg1 or skills like :arg2 .... or skills like :argN`, and put in as many placeholders are there's query terms. abetter setup would be to properly normalize your table and put the skills into their own table. then the problem basically goes away.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = array('developper','designer');
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($search) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT c.* FROM skills s JOIN candidates c 
        WHERE c.id=s.cid AND s.name IN($in)
        GROUP BY c.id";
$search[] = count($search);
$db->prepare($sql)->execute($search);
```